# Subtracting TimeSpan from date

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timespan

I want to subtract a time-span from a date-time object using a 30-day month and ignoring leap years etc.

```
Date is 1983/5/1 13:0:0 (y/m/d-h:m:s)
Time span is 2/4/28-2:51:0 (y/m/d-h:m:s)
```

I can use DateTime and TimeSpan objects to do this, after converting years and months of the time-span to days (assuming a 30 day month and a ~364 day year).

```
new DateTime(1981,5,1,13,0,0).Subtract(new TimeSpan(878,13,51,0));
```

With this i get the result:

```
{12/4/1978 11:09:00 PM}
```

Above answer obviously doesn't ignore the factors i want ignored and gives me an accurate answer. But in this case that's not what i want so i wrote the below code.

```
public static CustomDateTime operator -(CustomDateTime DT1,CustomDateTime DT2)
{
    CustomDateTime retVal = new CustomDateTime();
    try
    {
        const int daysPerYear = 364.25;
        const int monthsPerYear = 12;
        const int daysPerMonth = 30;
        const int hoursPerDay = 24;
        const int minutesPerHour = 60;

        retVal.Minute = DT1.Minute - DT2.Minute;
        if (retVal.Minute < 0)
        {
            retVal.Minute += minutesPerHour;
            DT1.Hour -= 1;
        }
        retVal.Hour = DT1.Hour - DT2.Hour;
        if (retVal.Hour < 0)
        {
            retVal.Hour += hoursPerDay;
            DT1.Day -= 1;
        }
        retVal.Day = DT1.Day - DT2.Day;
        if (retVal.Day < 0)
        {
            retVal.Day += daysPerMonth;
            DT1.Month -= 1;
        }
        retVal.Month = DT1.Month - DT2.Month;
        if (retVal.Month < 0)
        {
            retVal.Month += monthsPerYear;
            DT1.Year -= 1;
        }
        retVal.Year = DT1.Year - DT2.Year;                
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
    return retVal;
}
```

Then i get:

```
1981/0/3-10:9:0
```

This is pretty close to what i'm after except i shouldn't get 0 for month and year should be 1980. Any kind of help is appreciated.

---

Just to make things clear again; in this context I have to use a 30-day month and ignore leap-years, different numbers of months, etc. Its a weird thing to do, i know. So I'm pretty much after a 'wrong answer' as opposed to the exact answer given by the managed classes.

Comment: What do you mean, "if I do this manually"?

Comment: I believe it means "by hand, on paper".  And I have no idea what he means by "native classes".

Comment: yes. subtract minutes(m1) from minutes(m2). if m1 < m2 then 60 to m1 and subtract 1 from hours, then subtract m2 from m1... just like i'd do it in paper.

Comment: "assuming a 30 day month"? how can you assume that?

Comment: @yodaj007 and i meant the DateTime object in the .Net framework. Forgive me if my descriptions aren't technically correct.

Comment: And there isn't a zero month...

Comment: @Simon Mourier 
I use this in the context of Astrology. I have to assume a 30 day month.

Comment: @yodaj007 
So how can i avoid getting a 0 month on paper?

Comment: Subtract a year, add 365 days, or 366 days, depending on a yeap year.  How did you get your answer?  878 days is over 2 years, but somehow you're arriving at 1981 still.

Comment: I need to subtract 2 years 4 months and 28 days. I arrived at 878 days using (365*2)+(30*4)+28.

Comment: I understand now.  Got it.  Code added to the end of my answer.  Does this accomplish what you need?

Answer (score 2):

If you're estimating a month at 30 days, of course your math will be off.  When you subtract 878 days from 5/1/1981, .Net is giving you the *exact* difference, not an estimate, and this difference accounts for leap years, if there are any.  The error is not in the Subtract(...) method - it is in your own "manual" calculation.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1981, 5, 1, 13, 0, 0);
TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(878, 13, 51, 0);

dt.Ticks
    624931668000000000

t.Ticks
    759090600000000

dt.Ticks - t.Ticks
    624172577400000000

new DateTime(dt2)
    {12/4/1978 11:09:00 PM}
    Date: {12/4/1978 12:00:00 AM}
    Day: 4
    DayOfWeek: Monday
    DayOfYear: 338
    Hour: 23
    Kind: Unspecified
    Millisecond: 0
    Minute: 9
    Month: 12
    Second: 0
    Ticks: 624172577400000000
    TimeOfDay: {23:09:00}
    Year: 1978
```

These are the total ticks since the epoch.  Do this math, then convert back into a datetime.

<strike>Also: correct your math.  878 days is 2 years and 148 days.  5/1/1981 is the 121st day of the year, so subtract 120 to get Jan 1, 1979.  This leaves 28 days.  Start counting backwards from the end of 1978, and you get very close to the .Net answer.  Your own answer isn't anywhere close.</strike>

**EDIT based on feedback**

```
// zh-Hans is a chinese culture
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("zh-Hans");
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1981, 5, 1, 13, 0, 0, ci.Calendar);
TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(878, 13, 51, 0);
```

Please note that you are *still* subtracting 878 days.  The length of a month would be irrelevant in that case based on the Julian calendar.  You will probably need to find the correct culture code for your particular calendar, then try this.  **However**, with this calendar, I still arrive at the same answer above.

Beyond doing this, I am unsure how else to do the math.  If you can provide a link to how you are doing it by hand, I can help code it for you.

**EDIT 2**

I understand now.  Try this:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1981, 5, 1, 13, 0, 0, ci.Calendar);

int years = 878 / 365;
int remainingDays = 878 % 365;
int months = remainingDays / 30;
remainingDays = remainingDays % 30;
TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(years * 365 + months * 30 + remainingDays);
DateTime newdate = dt.Subtract(t);
```

Comment: What if i 'have to' estimate a 30 day month. How do i go about doing that?

Comment: Why would you want to arrive at an (incorrect) estimate instead of the exact answer?

Comment: Because i'm using it in the context of eastern astrology. There's a particular calculation that uses a 30-day month.

Comment: I see.  I am updating my answer.  Give me a moment.

Comment: @yodaj007 878 days isn't exactly my input here. I just need to subtract 2 years 4 months, 28 days etc etc from the given date. 878 is how i roughly calculated the 2 years 4 months 28 days in to just days because the timespan class doesn't take in years and months.
I've also included my 'manual' code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assume a 30-day month. You are specifying that you want to subtract 878 days. The managed classes (I'm assuming you mean managed when you say native) are designed to factor in leap-years, different numbers of months, etc.

Using the managed classes will not give you a 0 for a month.